# How to make HTML text hidden until clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to learn how to make HTML text toggle with jQuery, which is pretty easy in itself, but I want the text to be hidden automatically until it is clicked on with a button. I've looked it up and I can't find how to do this. I figured it should be easy, and I have this part

```
<h4 id="text1">This is some toggleable text</h4>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#text1").toggle();
    });
});
```

Which works fine as a regular toggle, but this leaves the text there until first clicked on.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYYeEB

Comment: You just need to add `display: none` css to your #text1 or any other text you want initially hidden.  `#text1 { display: none; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `show`,`hide` and `toggle` functions simply alter the CSS `display` property to have either `display: block;` or `display: none;`.

To start with your element hidden just set the style attribute  `style="display:none;"`.

Comment: or add to the css `#text1 { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $("#button1").click(toggle);
  }
);

function toggle() {
  $("#text1").toggle();
}

toggle();
```

Calling `toggle` at the bottom will auto hide the element. This still isn't the greatest since the element will show until this code runs.

But you can always change the HTML to read like this:

```
<h4 id="text1" style="display:none">This is some toggleable text</h4>
```

Then you don't need to call `toggle` the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text1").css("display", "none");//you just have to add this line 
  $("#button1").click(function() {
  $("#text1").toggle();
 });
});
</script>
```